# Best Way to Implement Notification System with Express.js, React, and Socket.io?

Tags: reactjs, express, socket.io, notifications

I'm working on a project that allows users to create projects and invite other users to join their projects. I would like to implement a real-time notification system for this but I'm not sure what's the best way to implement it. The way I'm doing it right now is I have a component connect to `/ws-notifications` namespace on mount and then join a room that's unique to them (im just using their mongodb Id as the room name).

```
/********************** SERVER - app.js *************************/
var notifications = io.of('/ws-notifications')
.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  //connects each user to a room specific to them to listen for notifications
  var room = socket.handshake.query.user;
  socket.join(room);
  ...
});
```

Then when the project owner sends a user an invite, I emit to that user an event called `"new-notifications"`.

```
/*************** CLIENT - InviteModal.js ***************/
class InvitationModal extends Component {
  ...
  componentDidUpdate(){
    if(!this.props.loading)
        document.getElementById('submit-button').disabled = false;

    //invitation was sent successfully created, clear form data
    //and send the signal to the intvitee via socket io
    if(!this.props.loading && this.props.successMessage){
        //this.state.id holds the invitee's id
        if(this.state.id)
            this.state.socket.emit("send-notification", this.state.id)
        //clear invite success message and other state after timeout
        setTimeout(this.props.clearProcessData, 3000);
    } 
  }  
}

/****************** SERVER - app.js *********************/
var notifications = io.of('/ws-notifications')
.on('connection', (socket)=>{
  //connects each user to a room specific to them to listen for notifications
  var room = socket.handshake.query.user;
  socket.join(room);

  socket.on('send-notification', (user)=>{
    socket.to(user).emit('new-notification');
  })
});
```

Back on the invitee's page, when this event is emitted I just make a call to the api through an action to get all notifications for that user.

```
  /********************** CLIENT - Nav.js ***********************/
  class Nav extends Component {
    constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
        socket: null
      }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
      this.props.getNotifications();       

      this.setState({...this.state, socket: io('http://localhost:8000/ws-notifications?user=${this.props.user._id}')})
    }
    ...
    componentDidUpdate((prevProps, prevState){
      //prevents checks if socket is already connected to prevent creating multiple unnecessary connections
      if(this.state.socket && !prevState.socket){  
        //listens for new notifications
        this.state.socket.on("new-notification", ()=>{
          //dispatches action to get notifications from api
          this.props.getNotifications();
        });
       }
    }
  }
```

I believe that's all the relevant code. If there's any more context needed please let me know and ill add it. Doing it this way works as intended but I want to know if there is maybe a simpler solution and if there's is a more efficent way of getting live notifications. Would a simple `SetInterval()` work well enough? Would calling the api on the server then emitting the data to the client with the web socket be more efficent? Thanks for any help/advice in advance.